# Загрузка проекта на хостинг

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, servlet, jdbc

Я учусь, сделал небольшой проект. Использовал: IntelliJ IDEA 2019 Ultimate, java, jdbc, mysql, сервлеты. Вопрос в том, как и куда можно загрузить проект + базу данных? У меня получилось загрузить проект на github, и я пытался найти инфу по своему вопросу, но у меня ничего не получалось.

Если вы не понимаете мой вопрос, не ругайте. Я просто хочу разобраться. Я не прошу сделать всё за меня, просто направить на ресурсы или гайды по данной теме

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен полноценный компьютер, доступный из интернета. Для этого нужно:

1. Собственно компьютер. Это может быть как и ваш личный (что очень сложно, дорого и не стоит того) так и арендованный. В последнем случае можно взять любого хостера и у него арендовать. Бывают и бесплатные тарифы на попробовать на месяц-другой.
2. На компьютер надо установить нужные программы. Минимум - сервер для БД и Java/Tomcat.
3. Настроить все эти программы, убедиться, что ваше приложение корректно соединяется с БД, БД существует и приложение доступно из интернета по IP адресу и порту арендованного компьютера.

Answer (score 3):

```
https://www.heroku.com/
```

есть бесплатный тариф,
в инете есть мануалы как заливать,
синхронизируется с git

Answer (score 0):

Делал вот так:

Проект полностью рабочий на домашнем пк. В локальной сети все работало. Для его вывода в глобальную сеть, настраивал роутинг на свитче/роутере/маршрутизаторе (смотря как у вас все организовано) чтобы айпи локального компьютера формата `192.168.0.23` (к примеру) маршрутировался на внешний айпи, присвоенный вам провайдером, к примеру (278.354.78.987).

Далее ваш проект будет доступен в интернете по адресу: `278.354.78.987:8080`(или другой порт, указанный в вашем проекте)/